A way to make Chrome remember client certificate?
Is there a way to make Chrome remember client SSL certificate (for mTLS)?
Each time some JS on page sends a request, it shows a popup window asking if I want to use certificate, which happens every 10-20 seconds (and which is super annoying).
Unlike Chrome, FF, for example, has a tick: "Remember certificate for this site".
Is there something like this in Chrome?

It seems that server was missing this setting:
tls.set_session_id_context("XXXXX".as_bytes()).unwrap();

